# Problem with displaying contents in multiple columns using "ui grid" class of semantic ui in react js

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui

Below is the component where semantic ui classes were used

```
import React from 'react'

class Gridview extends React.Component{
   render(){
     return(
       <div>
         <div class="ui grid">
          <div class ="column">
           <div class ="ui segment">
             {this.props.data.id}<br/>
             {this.props.data.name}<br/>
             {this.props.data.price}<br/>
           </div>
          </div>
         </div>
      </div>
     )
   }
}

export default Gridview
```

Below is the component where the above component is used to map the content. But when displayed in UI, it's appearing in one column instead of multiple columns:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Gridview from './Gridview'

class Product extends Component{
    constructor(){
      super();
      this.state = {  
         data:[
          {
           "id":1,
           "name":"Watch",
           "price":250
          },
          {
           "id":2,
           "name":"Wine",
           "price":252
          },
          {
           "id":3,
           "name":"Mobile",
           "price":289
          }
        ]
      }
    }
    render(){
       return(
        <div>
          {this.state.data.map((item) =>  <Gridview data ={item} />)}  
        </div>
       )
    }
}

export default Product
```

Comment: Do you importing semantic ui library?

Comment: I have done npm install 'semantic-ui' and added the "//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.4.2/dist/semantic.min.css" in index.html as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes.** It will show your data in 1 column as you have added only 1 column,

```
<div class="ui grid">
    <div class="column">
        <div class="ui segment">
            {this.props.data.id}<br />
            {this.props.data.name}<br />
            {this.props.data.price}<br />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you want `3 column grid` then you have to add `3` div with class `column` with the wrapper `row` div,

```
<div className="three column row">
    <div className="column"> {this.props.data.id}</div>
    <div className="column"> {this.props.data.name}</div>
    <div className="column"> {this.props.data.price}</div>
</div>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-8hbu3f)

You can refer the [Grid](https://semantic-ui.com/collections/grid.html) here.

**Note:** In React instead of `class` we use `className`.

---

**Update**

For the requirement,

*I am having a list of data with the params id,name & price.I need the list to span across multiple column not the individual params*

You need to change your parent component structure.

```
<div className="ui grid">
    <div className="three column row">
        {this.state.data.map((item) =>  <Gridview data ={item} />)}
    </div>
</div>
```

In `Gridview` component, you should only have your `column`,

```
<div className="column"> 
   {this.props.data.id} <br/> 
   {this.props.data.name} <br/>
   {this.props.data.price} 
</div>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-5uuugl)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am having a list of data with the params id,name & price.I need the list to span across multiple column not the individual params